# Confirm the action in a modal window into ruby watir

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog, watir

How I can push "OK" into modal dialog window in IE using ruby watir?

Modal dialog JavaScript:

```
jQuery('#yt100').on('click', function(){return confirm('modal dialog window text');});
```

I need click OK on this window. 
what I'm trying to:

```
browser.execute_script("window.confirm = function() {return true}")
```

But for some reason it does not work.

This method is described in the article: http://itreallymatters.net/post/1482786902/testing-webpages-with-javascript-popups-correctly#.WLGKXdLyh0w

Comment: Take a look at http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Alert#ok-instance_method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I solved this problem by using chrome instead ie